# How to stream video besides camera in libstreaming android

Tags: java, android, libstreaming

I'm looking to stream media from my android phone over RTSP. I looked at the libstreaming library, but that only streams the camera. Does anyone know how to stream JUST the media from a surfaceview, or similar?

Thanks